# Gmail not allowing to embed my website link in the email message PHP

Tags: php, email

```
$from = "abc@abcwebsite.jp";
$subject="車を売る 問い合わせ";
 $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
 $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$vdetails="";
$to="abcmail@gmail.com";
$vdetails.="<table><tr><td>車名: 小林様</td></tr>";
$vdetails.="<tr><td>年:1990 </td></tr>";
$vdetails.="<tr><td>車検:トヨタ</td></tr>";
$vdetails.="<tr><td>KM:1225</td></tr>";
$vdetails.="<tr><td>希望価格:東京蒲田</td></tr>";
$vdetails.="<tr><td>状態コメント:いい</td></tr><tr><td><a href='www.abcwebsite.jp'>www.abcwebsite.jp</a></td></tr></table>";
$body.=$vdetails;
$res=mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers); 
if($res){
    echo "done...===48776====>";
}
```

Email code works fine and mail shows in gmail inbox without Anchor tag Link.

But When i try to add a anchor tag link pointing to my domain website url it does not go in Gmail inbox and even not show in spam.

I am using php simple mail not smtp.

Email example:
Please visit the page pointing to abcexample.com

Comment: No error or something?

Comment: No error  it sents always but when we add a link to domain  in message then it sends from php side but do not show in gmail inbox/spam

Comment: Thanks it was solved issue was solved by allowing email filters of email provider